# ECONNREFUSED error trying migration with NestJS, TypeORM, Docker, Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, nestjs, typeorm

Using NestJS, docker-compose and Postgres on Ubuntu 20.4

Trying my first database migration with this app:

`npx typeorm migration:create -n mushroomRefactor`

`npm run build`

`npx typeorm migration:run`

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3"

services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mushrooms-psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
  
volumes:
  mushrooms-psql:
```

ormconfig.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5423,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'pass123',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/*.js'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
};
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

# install app dependencies 
# use wildcard * to install package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# bundle app source
COPY . . 

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run build

# entry file to run the app
CMD [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

But it is returning:
`Error during migration run: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5423 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16) { errno: -111, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 5423 }`

Comment: Your docker compose  is running, right? `docker-compose ps`?

Comment: Yup!
world-of-mushrooms_db_1      docker-entrypoint.sh postgres     Up     0.0.0.0:5432/tcp,:::5432->5432/tcp

Comment: And you're running this command from your machine, not from within the docker container, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so... I'm not inside the container's shell. In case you are aware of it, I have been following the tutorial on the NestJS website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check port you've set, it's different

Comment: Ah! Well spotted. Thank you.